# Could not parse the remainder after passing a method with attr to Django template

Tags: django, python-requests, jinja2, python-asyncio, htmx

Getting this error `Could not parse the remainder: '(module.url)' from 'call_url(module.url)'` in Django template calling a method `call_url` with argument from HTMX request.

```
<p>
<span class="fw-semibold">URL:</span> {{ module.url }}
<span class="ms-3" hx-get="{{ call_url(module.url) }}" hx-swap="innerHTML">Check URL response</span>
</p>
```

I also tried with no square brackets `{{ call_url module.url }}`, but it did not help

Method call_url is passed to context:

```
async def get_project(request, project_id: int):
    """Detailed project view with modules."""
    project = await Project.objects.prefetch_related("modules").aget(pk=project_id)
    return render(
        request,
        "monitor/project.html",
        context={"project": project, "call_url": call_url},
    )

async def call_url(url: str):
    """Make a request to an external url."""
    # TODO: add headers to aiohttp.ClientSession
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url=url) as response:
            response_code = response.status
            if response_code == 200:
                return HttpResponse(content="Page response OK", status=200)
            else:
                return HttpResponse(
                    content=f"Error. Response code id {response_code}",
                    status=response_code,
                )
```

Tried to pass url directly to `async def call_url(url: str = "https://www.google.com"):` and call it from template `hx-get="{{ call_url }}"` but I get an error:

```
Not Found: /project/1/<coroutine object call_url at 0x000001A3A95AA940>
[02/May/2023 22:02:02] "GET /project/1/%3Ccoroutine%20object%20call_url%20at%200x000001A3A95AA940%3E HTTP/1.1" 404 3710
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an URL for the endpoint with `url` template tag passing `module.url` as an argument. Assuming the `urls.py` looks something like this:

```
from django.urls import path

import myapp.views

urlpatterns = [
    path("call/<str:url>/", myapp.views.call_url),
    ...
]
```

In the template:

```
hx-get="{% url 'call' module.url %}"
```

Note: you may have to apply `urllib.parse.unquote` to decode the URL string.